# Getting the name of a closed YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, account-management

On **YouTube**, I would like to start a new channel with a particular name. However, that name has previously been used by a channel that is now closed.

The channel-page shows the following message:

> "This channel is no longer available because the user has closed their
>   account."

**Is there any way that I could get the name of that channel for my own, new account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way you can do that. This kind of restriction is not only for YouTube Channel names but also for email-addresses from all service providers and many more.